# How to programmatically execute commands in mac terminal using C#/Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I am able to open a new terminal window using a `System.Diagnostics.Process`, but cannot write anything to the terminal using `StandardInput.WriteLine`.

The terminal window opens but no commands are then written to the terminal window.

Example Code:

```
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = @"/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UserName = System.Environment.UserName
    };

    using (var process = Process.Start (startInfo)) {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine ("nuget"); // cannot get anything written to the terminal
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the code as below:

```
    public static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start ();

        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
            Console.WriteLine (proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine ());
        }
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        ExecuteCommand("nuget");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work as expected on my end. I did initially try `StartInfo.Arguments` but nothing gets input to the terminal.

Comment: @SamuelG then you can remove that argument and trying again, it was work for Ubuntu exactly.

Comment: yes, I have tried the arguments and no arguments combo - as well as `StandardInput.WriteLine`. Not getting the result on **mac**